# iOS: Can't set image in iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, icarousel

I'm using `iCarousel` in my `objective-c` application. Each carousel `view` contains an `image`. So in the

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

I set the `image` like that:

```
[carouselImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myStringUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:placeholderImage]];
```

The application crash in this line. And this is the error:

```
    -[CarouselUIView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CarouselUIView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x123d10a70'
```

When I searched about that I found that many solutions suggest the use of the `-ObjC` flag iin the `Build Settings` but I have already this flag.

**Edit:** Additional code

This is the whole code of my function:

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UIImageView * carouselImage;
    if (view == nil) {
        NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.carouselItemView];
        CarouselUIView * carousselView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];
        view = carousselView;
    }

    carouselImage = (UIImageView *) [view viewWithTag:0];


    [carouselImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myStringUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagePlaceholder]];
    return view;
}
```

And the `CarouselView`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CarouselUIView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * carouselImage;


@end
```

Comment: can you show some additional code

Comment: Yes of course !

Comment: The code you provided here is not enough to provide you proper direction for solution. Any way but my wild guess is the `carsoulImage` is not the `UIImageView` but it is `CarouselUIView`

Comment: check  carouselImage class name. using isKindOfClass.

Comment: can you add related code related to this viewForItemAtIndex

Comment: Check my edit please

Comment: why did you use unarchiveObjectWithData  ?

Comment: I found it in an example and I was using it in another project where it works

Comment: Can you please correct me? because I know that something wrong is there

Comment: no need of this `NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.carouselItemView];
        CarouselUIView * carousselView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];
        view = carousselView;`

Comment: Just try to change this line `view = carousselView;` to `view = carousselView.carouselImage;` may this will solve your error

Comment: Second thing I like to tell you is never use `[view viewWithTag:0];` Must change tag value to other then **0**. As all view's tag property is set to **0** by default

Comment: @TheiOSDev thank you! Can you please make it as an answer?

Comment: Okay will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking to your given code the line you used to init the view with imageView has issue.

```
[view viewWithTag:0];
```

Must change tag value to other then **0**. As all view's tag property is set to **0** by default.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this may helping you.
**If carousel contains ImageView Only**

```
-(UIView *) carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UIImageView  *imageView = (UIImageView *)view;
    if (!imageView) {
        imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ViewWidth(carousel), 250)];
        imageView.tag = 100;

    }
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myStringUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagePlaceholder]];

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: the `iCarousel ` datasource returns the `-(UIView *)` not `-(UIImageView *)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can you explain why there is no need of the piece of code you mentioned in your last comment?

Comment: you can return because UIImageView is the subclass of UIView so.

Comment: but in your answer you return the `-(UIImageView *)`

Comment: Ah okay. And what if I have in the CarouselUIView other elements such as `UILabel` and `UIImage`?